# Get DOM hierarchy level of element (count descendant levels)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an efficient way to count the deepest descendant level of a specific element?

Example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">first</li>
    <li class="active">second</li>
    <li class="last"><a>third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`#wrapper` should return a descendant level of `4` because the deepest chain goes like this: `#wrapper > ul > li > a`.

`li.first` should return `1` because it has no children and `li.last` should return `2` because of `li.last > a`.

I could do a `$('#wrapper').find(*)` and iterate through all results, which should be quite slow for elements that have lots of descendants, especially for the `body` element.

Here is a start for experimenting: http://jsbin.com/ixeWaja/1/edit

Any ideas how to efficiently solve this?

Comment: _"Is there an efficient way"_ define _efficint_, but basically, **No.**

Comment: If `#wrapper > ul > li > a` is 3 (i.e. `#wrapper` has 3 levels of descendants), then shouldn't `li.first` be 0 and `li.last` be 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efficiency is probably not going to be your greatest concern if you ultimately need the depth, but this is  a pretty concise and efficient way to do it.

```
var el = $("#wrapper");
var i = 0;

while ((el = el.children()).length) {
    i++;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ixeWaja/4/

Comment: OMG that's beautiful, here I was starting to code away this big recursive iterator. But of course jQuery merges the `.children()` of all elements contained in the jQuery object so you'll get to the deepest possibility that way.